# Showing output in web browser

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application. These are the classes:

**RunBatchFile.java**

```
public class RunBatchFile {

private Boolean isSuccessful;
private String content;

public void RunningBatchCommand() {

    String filePath = "C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/test.bat";
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

        int exitVal = p.waitFor();

        if (exitVal == 0)

        {
            isSuccessful = true;
        }
        else {
            isSuccessful = false;
        }

        System.out.println(isSuccessful);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public RunBatchFile(Boolean isSuccessful) {
    this.isSuccessful = isSuccessful;
    this.content = content;
}

public RunBatchFile(String format) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Boolean getisSuccessful() {
    return isSuccessful;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
  }
}
```

**BatchFileController**

```
@RestController
public class BatchFileController {

private static final String template = "Sum, %s!";
private static boolean isSuccessful;

@RequestMapping("/runbatchfile")
@ResponseBody
public RunBatchFile runbatchFile(@RequestParam(value = "isSuccessful") Boolean isSuccessful) {
    return new RunBatchFile(String.format(template, isSuccessful));
  }
}
```

The runBatchFile.java class executes a batch file and will show output as either true or false depending on whether the batch file has executed its commands correctly or not. I want to display that output on a web browser therefore i have created the BatchFileController.java class.

I get the error:

> Required Boolean parameter 'isSuccessful' is not present

How do i edit my codes to make this work? Which means,  either {true} or {false} is shown on the web browser when i run `localhost:8080/runbatchfile`?

Comment: Try going to `localhost:8080/runbatchfile?isSuccessful=true`

Comment: I get the output as: `{"isSuccessful":null,"content":null}` Why is isSuccessful showing null instead of {true} or {false} ? What changes should i make in the codes such that {true} or {false} is shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are doing. The issue you are having with your controller is that you have defined your method to require a boolean parameter. Given your scenario, that would not make sense, as you would not tell the endpoint the result of the script running; the endpoint tells you that. Your method return type should be boolean instead.

Generally this would be the way to go about this if it is a short running script. I tested with a simple ping command and things worked out. Pointing to an invalid IP failed.

If the script takes a lot of time, you're going to want to go async where you submit a job, and you can check back with a different method to see what the status is.

I would have a class to run your batch file:

```
public class RunBatchFile {

    public boolean runBatch() {

        String filePath = "C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/test.bat";
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

            int exitVal = p.waitFor();

            return exitVal == 0;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And then in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/runbatchfile")
public boolean runbatchFile() {
    RunBatchFile rbf = new RunBatchFile();
    return rbf.runBatch();
}
```

If you want to wrap your results so your response isn't just a true/false string. Note that the return type of the method has changed to a simple [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object):

**Class**

```
public class RunBatchFile {

    public ResultWrapper runBatch() {

        String filePath = "C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/test.bat";
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

            int exitVal = p.waitFor();

            return new ResultWrapper(exitVal == 0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResultWrapper(false);
        }
    }

}
```

**Wrapper Class**

```
public class ResultWrapper {

    private boolean result;

    public ResultWrapper(boolean result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public boolean getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
@RequestMapping("/runbatchfile")
public ResultWrapper runbatchFile() {
    RunBatchFile rbf = new RunBatchFile();
    return rbf.runBatch();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked ! I have one more small question. How do i display it as` {true}` instead of `true`?

Comment: I updated the comment to show how to wrap up the results

Comment: Hi @Brian i have one more doubt. How can i add a parameter to this java program lets say `fileName` where fileName represents a batch file that user wants to execute by typing the name of the batch file in the URL in web browser? I posted another question explaining everything in detail. Could you please take a look at it and help me? Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804776/run-batch-file-indicated-in-parameter-of-url I would greatly appreciate